# Why is it hard to find a Eevee in the Trophy Garden in Diamond and Pearl?

Tags: pokemon-diamond-pearl-platinum

It's just hard to find one Eevee in Pearl and Diamond. Why is it?

Comment: It is just like that. One can speculate that some Pokémon species are rarer in some areas than others, but that's about it.

Comment: While I admit this question may be poorly phrased, I think it entirely likely that the "Why?" is less "Why did the developers make this difficult?" and more **"Why am I having such a hard time finding an Eevee in the Trophy Garden?"** Considering some of the mechanics involved in determining which Pokemon are even *available* in this location at any given time (explained in the answer), I find it entirely plausible that the question asker is unaware of one or more of these mechanics and is thus confused by the lack of Eevee encountered.

Answer (score 1):

Eevee is a special Pokemon in the Trophy Garden, which means it has to be one of the last two Pokemon mentioned by the owner, Mr. Backlot. He mentions a new Pokemon every 24 hours and you can soft reset which Pokemon he mentions, but you have to do it in the first place, otherwise Eevee won't be there at all.

This also requires the National Pokedex, otherwise only the "normal" Pokemon appear in the Trophy Garden.

Finally, when Eevee does appear, it's still only a 5% chance, so you'll have to search for a while.

Comment: @TrentHawkins Thanks, I didn't consider it that way :)